# How do you use FIML with a Mixed Measures Anova in R?

Tags: r, anova, missing-data

I am conducting a Mixed Measures Two-Way ANOVA in R to test the effect of an intervention. There are two conditions (control and intervention) with two time-points (pre-test and post-test). Each participant only went through one condition (either control or intervention) and there is only have one DV.

However, I have missing data. Does anyone know how to conduct a mixed measures two-way ANOVA in R using FIML? I could also use MI but my PI would like me to use FIML.

Below is the code I have for the MM Two-Way ANOVA. The code works, I just need to solve the missing data problem and am wondering if there is a different way to conduct the MM Two-Way Anova that would allow for that. I've used FIML with the Lavaan package before but I am not sure how to conduct a MM Two-Way Anova with Lavaan.

Thank you in advance!

```
library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
```

```
# Wide format
set.seed(123)
data("data")
data %>% sample_n_by(condition, size = 1)
```

```
# Convert id and time into factor variables
data <- data %>%
  gather(key = "time", value = "score", t1, t2) %>%
  convert_as_factor(ID, time)
```

```
# Inspect some random rows of the data by groups
set.seed(123)
data %>% sample_n_by(condition, time, size = 1)

# Summary Statistics
data %>%
  group_by(time, condition) %>%
  get_summary_stats(score, type = "mean_sd")

#visualization
bxp <- ggboxplot(
  sdrcdata, x = "time", y = "score",
  color = "condition", palette = "jco"
)
bxp
```

```
#Two-way mixed ANOVA test
res.aov <- anova_test(
  data = data, dv = score, wid = ID,
  between = condition, within = time
)
get_anova_table(res.aov)
```